# How can I create a visual list of Visio component images in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visio

I am trying to take a list of Visio Components and display the shapes in a ListView, ListBox  or something similar. I currently have a foreach loop that cycles through the "Component"'s. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by component; what object type in the Visio Object Model is a component?


What do you want to display in the list, the name of the component, an image of the component, or something else?

Comment: Excuse my terminology. With components I mean stencils, shapes etc. I need to create a stencil pallet, displaying the shapes and is ready for drag and drop. If there is an easy(er) way, I would be grateful!